# Break table in two pieces underneath each other

Tags: tables, spacing, formatting

I have a table with too many columns so that it overlaps with the right column of the page. Now, I would like to break the table into to pieces, so that columns 35-50 are placed below columns 10-30, while remaining to be the same table.

[image]

Currently, this is my code:

```
\documentclass{eusflat2021}

\begin{table}[ht]
\begin{center}
\vspace{1ex}
\begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|} \hline
    {\bf GTW} & {\bf 10} & {\bf 15} & {\bf 20} & {\bf 25} & {\bf 30} & {\bf 35} & {\bf 40} & {\bf 45} & {\bf 50}  \\\hline
    Entropy &  & &&&&&&& \\
    IDF & 0.4301& 0.4552&0.4627&0.4648&4610&0.4523&0.4270&0.4349&0.4337 \\
    Normal & 0.4856 & 0.4802 &0.4769&0.4266&0.4181&0.4176&0.3877&0.3724&0.3555\\
    ProbIDF &0.3333&0.3628&0.3717&0.3831&0.3697&0.3773&0.3712&0.3608&0.3705\\
    Normal-alt & 0.5598&0.5066&0.5077&0.4685&0.4876&0.4784&0.44934515&0.4420\\
    \hline
\end{tabular}
\caption{\label{table}The number and caption of the table always appear below the table.}
\end{center}
\end{table}
```

I have found [this page](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/496230/two-tables-underneath-each-other-with-three-part-table), but it is unclear to me how I could implement that in my code.

Who could give me an example of how to do this?

Comment: Did you think of leaving the two-column mode just for the table with the `cuted` package?

Comment: What is a `cuted` package?

Comment: It's the name of the package, from the `sttools` bundle. It defines a `strip` environment, which leaves the two-column mode.

Comment: This can be simply done manually: (i) make a copy of table (ii) from the first table delete last four columns, (iii) from the second table delete except the four columns after the first one.

Comment: unrelated but note that `\bf` has not been defined by default in LaTeX since 1993. You may be better to use `\bfseries` as `\bf` is defined for compatibility in some but not all classes.

Comment: Thanks, David. Its there, because the class' template that I'm using, used `\bf`. Therefore, I think it is compatible for my class

Comment: Possibly related: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/277901/remove-specific-column-from-multiple-tables

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could either allow the table to occupy both columns in order to avoid the need to split the table. Alternative, I also included a version in which I split the table into three parts in order to allow it to fit into one of the columns.

[image]

Side note: The code contains some lines I personally would avoid, such as the `center` environment and the `\vspace`. I decided to keep them since this particular template also contained them. I however could not resist to change `\bf` to `\bfseries`.

```
\documentclass{eusflat2021}
\usepackage{lipsum} % For dummy text. Do not use in real document.
\usepackage{array}
\begin{document}
\begin{table*}
\begin{center}
\vspace{1ex}
\begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|} \hline
    {\bfseries GTW} & {\bfseries 10} & {\bfseries 15} & {\bfseries 20} & {\bfseries 25} & {\bfseries 30} & {\bfseries 35} & {\bfseries 40} & {\bfseries 45} & {\bfseries 50}  \\\hline
    Entropy &  & &&&&&&& \\
    IDF & 0.4301& 0.4552&0.4627&0.4648&4610&0.4523&0.4270&0.4349&0.4337 \\
    Normal & 0.4856 & 0.4802 &0.4769&0.4266&0.4181&0.4176&0.3877&0.3724&0.3555\\
    ProbIDF &0.3333&0.3628&0.3717&0.3831&0.3697&0.3773&0.3712&0.3608&0.3705\\
    Normal-alt & 0.5598&0.5066&0.5077&0.4685&0.4876&0.4784&0.44934515&0.4420 &\\
    \hline
\end{tabular}
\caption{\label{table}The number and caption of the table always appear below the table.}
\end{center}
\end{table*}
\lipsum

\begin{table}[ht]
\begin{center}
\vspace{1ex}
\setlength{\tabcolsep}{5pt}
\begin{tabular}{|l|*{3}{wc{4.5em}|}} \hline
    {\bfseries GTW} & {\bfseries 10} & {\bfseries 15} & {\bfseries 20} \\\hline
    Entropy    &        &        &         \\
    IDF        & 0.4301 & 0.4552 & 0.4627  \\
    Normal     & 0.4856 & 0.4802 & 0.4769  \\
    ProbIDF    & 0.3333 & 0.3628 & 0.3717  \\
    Normal-alt & 0.5598 & 0.5066 & 0.5077  \\
    \hline
    {\bfseries GTW}  & {\bfseries 25} & {\bfseries 30} & {\bfseries 35}  \\\hline
    Entropy    &        &        &         \\
    IDF        & 0.4648 & 4610   & 0.4523  \\
    Normal     & 0.4266 & 0.4181 & 0.4176  \\
    ProbIDF    & 0.3831 & 0.3697 & 0.3773  \\
    Normal-alt & 0.4685 & 0.4876 & 0.4784  \\
    \hline
    {\bfseries GTW}  & {\bfseries 40} & {\bfseries 45} & {\bfseries 50}  \\\hline
    Entropy    &            &        &        \\
    IDF        & 0.4270     & 0.4349 & 0.4337 \\
    Normal     & 0.3877     & 0.3724 & 0.3555 \\
    ProbIDF    & 0.3712     & 0.3608 & 0.3705 \\
    Normal-alt & 0.44934515 & 0.4420 &        \\
    \hline    
\end{tabular}
\caption{\label{table}The number and caption of the table always appear below the table.}
\end{center}
\end{table}
\lipsum
\end{document}
```